# Wagtail api add fields to pages endpoint

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, wagtail

I have been trying to follow the following docs

http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.6.3/reference/contrib/api/installation.html?highlight=api

for my wagtail 1.6.3 instance.

It tells me to add a field to the api_fields array in classes that extend page.

So I have tried this:

```
class HomePage(HeaderPage):
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)

    main_image = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+'
    )

    content_panels = HeaderPage.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('body', classname="full"),
        ImageChooserPanel('main_image')
    ]

    test = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="test");

    api_fields = ['test', 'body', 'main_image','header_image', 'show_in_menus']
```

But I am only getting these fields on the detail page and on the /api/v1/pages/ endpoint it only shows the title and meta data field. How can I add more fields that will show on that enpoint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You add fields to the listing endpoint by specifying them in the API URL, e.g.

http://localhost:8000/api/v2/pages/?type=blog.BlogPage&fields=body

See http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.7/advanced_topics/api/v2/usage.html#custom-page-fields-in-the-api for more details.

Comment: Thanks I thought there would be a way to show a common field for all pages(without that type option), but it doesn't look that way.

Comment: The thing which wasn't clear from the docs is that you need to specify the fields you've added as `api_fields` on the querystring. You can also specify all api fields with `fields=*`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what version this started by according to v2.2.2 you can list all fields by using `?fields=*`

example:

`http://localhost:8000/api/v2/pages/?type=home.HomePage&fields=*`

Just be sure you include the ?type= or else it will not expose the `api_fields`

http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.2.2/advanced_topics/api/v2/usage.html#all-fields